# How can I display a specific ad from an ad_unit using Google DFP?

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

Our website is using Google DFP to display custom ads on specific pages.

Our DFP setup is simple:

- We have created 10 *Ad units*
- Each *ad unit* has a number of *ads* added to it.
- Each *ad unit* has a specific place on the website.

Everything is working great thus far. Each *ad unit* on the website is showing *ads* at 'random' based on the available views and such.

In some specific cases, it is required to force a specific *ad* from an *ad unit* for displaying. However I am unable to find any documentation on how to accomplish this. I could really use some help.

I know the most obvious solution would be to create a new *ad unit* and put a single *ad* in there, but this is not desired as this would mean each *ad* (100+) would need it's own *ad unit*.

So in short, how do I tell Google DFP to display a specific *ad* from a specific *ad unit*?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into DFP and create a new line item and associated it with the Ad creative you want to see, next create an AdUnit that matches a key/value of your choosing. Make sure that AdUnit has priority over the others. Let say category=sports.

The when you create the Ad slot in GPT pass those values in the targeting.
see [Setting Targeting and Sizes](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1697712?hl=en)

Comment: Interesting! I have reserved a large block of time next monday to take a closer look at the information you provided. I'll let you know if this meets all requirements. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again. Please post your comment as a solution, so I can accept it as such :)
I do have a small follow-up question though. I have created a key-value item and a new AdUnit. Added 4 line items to it and specified the value to each. When I use setTargeting in my code, each of the 4 banners is displayed as requested. However if I define the slot only by AdUnit, without using setTargeting, no banner is displayed. Will lineitems with added key-values to it, only be displayed when calling these targeting values?

Comment: Addition. The priorities have been set correctly I assume? First selected AdUnit, then keyvalues. https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/3t3p3O07200q0m0e1h2S/Image%202018-08-08%20at%2011.04.36%20AM.png?v=ab475f7d

Comment: 'Fixed' it by adding a value 'random' to all ads and targeteting that value. Works great!